# Unable to move element from one parent to another in magento 2.1 layout

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, frontend, page-layouts

[image]

I am trying to move minicart-wrapper into page-wrapper, right now it is in the parent(header). What i have done so far,

> Path where i am over riding magento core module in my extended theme, my parent theme is luma:

Magento/app/design/frontend/classic/classic_theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="minicart.wrapper" destination="page.header" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Path of the default module that i am over riding in my theme:
>   Magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

I am following this (Rearrange elements)
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

I am confused how if they are referring to element by class or something else. I am doing it using class in my code.

Please help!!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check

> ../app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

here you find:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
```

I suspect this is the element you want to move.

To find the element you want it to move to check:

> ../app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml

Here you will find the element:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

So you should be able to change it like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="minicart" destination="checkout.header.container" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**How I found the elements generally speaking:**

You can enable layout hints in the admin backend. But I never found this useful so far.
So typically I just search in my IDE over all of the magento source code for some unique element like ie. a html class name or similar. You will then often find the code either in a layout xml, phtml or html.
If you found it in xml it should be simple to see the name of the element where the `htmlClass` is set.
If it's in an html or phtml file you need to search this file name in the layout(.xml) instruction files so you can find at what element it is attached. That gives you the element name then you can use for further actions.
To finally see if I got the right element I add a remove instruction into the appropriate layout file.

Comment: Yes you are right i am looking to move the block you mentioned
When using this,
<move element="minicart" destination="page.header" after="-"/>
Its not making any difference

Comment: And when using this, with body and page tags, its not rendering the cart,
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
  <move element="minicart" destination="page.header" after="-"/>
 </body>
</page>

Comment: My block in magento 2.1,
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="cart/minicart.phtml">

Comment: I have successfully moved the element to the page.wrapper with the code above in default.xml where you placed it. Have you flushed your caches? (especially layout instructions, I have disabled all caches on dev)

Comment: Ohh sorry. Its working fine for page.wrapper(page-wrapper) but when i am changing destination to page.header(page-header) or block.cms.link.inline(block-cms-link-inline) its not working, it not even rendering.

Comment: I updated the answer, it should work but I haven't tested it again.

Comment: can you please elaborate where can i get this destination from "checkout.header.container"?

Comment: its not rendering minicart for me when using checkout.header.container

Comment: I've updated the answer.
I can't test it now unfortunately cause I have completely removed the header and I don't have a blank installation ready now, sorry!

Comment: Awesome, it got it. Thanks alot once again for your precious time.